# Error Quarto require invalid module (bertin.js)

Tags: javascript, module, observable, require, quarto

I have developed the library [bertinjs](https://github.com/neocarto/bertin) which allows to make svg interative maps. In [Observable](https://observablehq.com/@neocartocnrs/hello-bertin-js?collection=@neocartocnrs/bertin), require("bertin") works. In [Quarto](https://quarto.org/docs/tools/rstudio.html), require("bertin") does not work. The following error is returned: OJS Error. RequireError$1: invalid module. See the issue on Github ([see](https://github.com/neocarto/bertin/issues/30)). It's weird. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

(Quarto dev here) I recently fixed a bug that would cause that behavior you're seeing. Can you try a release later than 0.9.430? Thanks!

Edit: I see now that `bertinjs` uses modern JS syntax, which the stable versions of the RStudio IDE don't yet support. Your example works on the latest Electron [daily builds](https://dailies.rstudio.com/), the right-most column on the linked page.