# How to convert observable output to raw markdown in Quarto?

Tags: javascript, r, quarto

I want to introduce interactivity to my reports. I believe this `.qmd` snippet should ([Quarto documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html#inline-code)) return markdown based on the slider input.

````
---
format: html
---
```{r}
#| echo: false
df = data.frame(id = 1:3, md = c("**bold**", "```\ncode```", "$x_{i} = 1$"))
write.csv(df, "df.csv")
r_out = df$md
```

```{ojs}
//| echo: false
data = FileAttachment("df.csv").csv()
viewof target_id = Inputs.range([1, 3], {value: 1, step: 1, label: "pick id"})
ojs_out = data.filter(x => target_id == x.id).map(x => x.md).toString()
```

OJS: ${ojs_out} should be one of: **bold**, ```code```, 
$x_{i} = 1$

R: `r r_out` works.
````

Gives

|  |
| --- |
| [image: Rendered Quarto] |

where the OJS **bold** sadly is not **bold**. I have tried to convert the string to markdown using [external JavaScript libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1319657/14853907), but was met with [RequireError: invalid module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72300480/14853907). Specifying [asis](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html#output-options) in the chunk options,`//| output: asis`, or `//| results: 'asis'`, doesn't seem to do anything to the OJS output.